# zookeeper jar not found in HBase MR job

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have a web UI that tries to spawn a MR job on HBase table. I keep getting this error though:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /opt/hadoop/mapreduce/system/job_201205251929_0007/libjars/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar does not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache.getTimestamp(DistributedCache.java:509)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.configureCommandLineOptions(JobClient.java:629)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:448)
```

I am running with hbase 0.90.4. HBase manages its own zookeeper. And, I confirmed that I have `/opt/hadoop/mapreduce/system/job_201205251929_0007/libjars/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar` in my HDFS. Is it looking in Local FS?

Comment: Is the HBase managing its own zookeeper or is zookeeper running externally?

Comment: HBase manages its own zookeeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I did not have core-site.xml on my classpath and it was taking local FS for fs.default.name instead of the HDFS. The jar existed in HDFS but it was looking in local FS.

Answer (score 1):

Any jar files accessed in the mapper or reducer need to be in the local filesystem on all the nodes in the cluster. Check your local FS.

Comment: Yes, its under my HBASE_HOME/lib directory on all nodes and that is also on the hadoop's classpath. There is something with the way the MR is spawned from the UI jsp page. Not sure where I'm missing the classpath